# How can multiple people add info to a SharePoint (2013) list and save that info at the same time without loosing the content the other has typed.

Tags: 2013

I have created a list in SharePoint 2013 - we will have multiple people in maybe one item in this list at the same time.  In my trial and error I discovered that if you both are working on the same line item and go to save it this error message appears.
[image]
Help, How can more that one individual be in at the same time and save each individuals updates to that one list item.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable content approval on the list. This enables the item requiring an approval and thus not losing the data.

Only approved content will get displayed.

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for, where do I do that??

Comment: You can go to list settings and then versioning..

Comment: Ok - So the problem that I have now with this approved content is that nobody else can go in and make changes until that first persons changes are approved. I love this idea but we want more than one person to be able to make changes at the same time and not get the message in RED. –  Jennifer Gammell 8 mins ago

Comment: It should not happen like that.. Users who has permission will be able to add/edit items. Item will be in pending state and need approval to make it (a major version) visible to all users.

Comment: Here I am back to square 1.  All these great changes have been made but when two people are in the same list item and make changes that red Conflict message comes up. AGAIN why cant two people do this at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use Office Web Apps and use office docs instead of a list for tracking some list data. It is a separate (now in SharePoint 2013) installation on a server that is not dependent on SharePoint that allows users to view Office docs in the browser. This allows for **coauthoring** in Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote, etc. In other words, more than one person can edit a document at the same time. In order to utilize Office Web Apps, you need to have a license key and the appropriate number of CALs to support it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219456(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Ok - So the problem that I have now with this approved content is that nobody else can go in and make changes until that first persons changes are approved. I love this idea but we want more than one person to be able to make changes at the same time and not get the message in RED.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by Design to prevent users from writing over other's edits.

If these are "Documents" then Office Web Apps provides shared editing as previously mentioned.

If these are "Items"

Options are

1) Embrace it - Enforce Checkout/Checkin to prevent overwriting.

2) Custom forms using JavaScript, and refresh Item and etag before saving.